# How to ensure testing environment for open source cpp projects?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, open-source

I'm writing open source tools for Bioinformatics in C++. I'm writing tests with the Google Test framework and want it to be portable alongside my code so that anybody that downloads the code will then be able to test the code.

Adding the test framework to the source code and writing a build script that deploys the framework and then runs it through a makefile is the solution I've come with to ensure portable deployment but it's very hacky and requires bundling a lot of dependencies.

How else are tests bundled for portability as C++ does not have a testing framework in the standard library?

Comment: maybe create a project with the testframework as submodule and use cmake to build the stuff

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing but it's very hackish. I'm hoping for an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve bringing in many more dependencies or making many more assumptions about the user's environments.

Comment: why is using cmake hacky? you could also think about wrapping the testing stuff and pack everything into a library?

Comment: the bundling of all the dependencies into the source code repo, and then orchestrating all of it with cmake seems hacky, not the act of using cmake, because I'm carrying all of the dependencies around with me inside the repo. 

Not only that, most projects I've seen open-sourced for C++ in Bioinformatics either have tests incorporated into the makefile, but that forgoes a proper testing framework, don't test at all, or create massive repositories filled with every dependency required. 

I'm trying to find a cleaner solution than carrying everything the project needs around inside the repo.

Comment: what about organizing everything into multiple projects in the same repo. one project builds the testing framework as a library and the other one uses it?

Comment: that still runs into bundling all the dependencies into the same repository and carrying them everywhere. It doesn't seem like this problem has a clear solution in the world of Cpp due to the lack of a standard library testing framework.

Comment: well git submodules solve that?